# How bind date to PrimeNG p-calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-calendar

```
<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="model.StartDate" name="StartDate"></p-calendar>
```

I have that in my HTML and I am trying to bind model.StartDate from my typescript file without success. I want to display date and time and the date should be according to the format on a user's machine. I am reading the date from an SQL datetime2(7) field. Example date is 2020-05-12 15:03:35.6830408

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
  StartDate
  dateTime = '2020-05-12 15: 03: 35.6830408'

  ngOnInit() {
    this.StartDate = new Date(this.dateTime)
  }
```

After this binding date is selected

```
<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="StartDate" name="StartDate"></p-calendar>
```